# Save results in a flat file using putty

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, unix, putty

I am doing `select * from tableName` in putty on postgresql database and needed to save the results from that query in a flat file.

I have tried using the following on postgresql command line -

```
[user@server-testdb01:~]$ psql test postgres psql (9.1.4) Type "help" for help.

test=# select * from tableName > a.txt 
test-#
```

After running the above statements I am not able to track where did the `a.txt` got saved, I have run few `find` commands but no luck.

Can anyone please correct me if I am doing anything wrong and help me how do I save results of postgres query in any flat file?

Answer (score 1):

in the psql command line tool

```
\o /my_dir/output/query_result.out

 Select * from foo;
\o
```

Use the \o command it works like spool does in oracle sqlplus. \o all by itself on a linestops spooling